# Irreducibility of a Polynomial after a substitution

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to determine whether the polynomial $f(x) = x^6 + 34x^4 + 4x^2 + 89 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Eisenstein's criterion doesn't help and I suppose I could determine whether $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ for some prime $p$, but I could potentially have to compute the greatest common divisor of $f$ (reduced mod $p$) with $x^{p^6} - x$ and I am trying to avoid that for now.

My question is: If I was to let $u = x^2$, then $f$ becomes $u^3 + 34u^2 + 4u + 89$. If I was to show that $u^3 + 34u^2 + 4u + 89$ was irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, would that imply that $x^6+ 34x^4 + 4x^2 + 89$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ as well?

Comment: What do you think happens if you try to use this method for $f(x) = x^2$ ?

Comment: Good point. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your polynomial is the square of $x^3-x-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$, hence it is, at best, the product of two irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$, $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, both of them having degree $3$. However, $p(x)$ splits over $\mathbb{F}_7$ as $(x^2-3)(x^4+2x^2+3)$, and such factorizations are not compatible unless $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

It is also interesting to point out that $89$ is a prime, hence $p(x)$ may split over $\mathbb{Q}$ only as $(x c(x)\pm 1)(x d(x)\pm 89)$. Moreover, $p(x)=p(-x)$ has to hold, hence it is not difficult to rule out every case.

Comment: +1 So here's how to show a polynomial is irreducible by successfully factoring it :)

Comment: So in general if I reduce $f$ mod $p_{1}$ and it factors as a two polynomials of degree $a_{1}$ and $b_{2}$ and I reduce $f$ mod $p_{2}$ and it factors as two polynomials of degree $a_{2}$ and $b_{2}$ and $a_{1} \neq a_{2}, b_{2}$, then we can conclude $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I agree, it is kind of hilarious but quite effective :)

Comment: @Oiler: not exactly. If by factoring over two different finite fields you get two partitions (given by the degrees of the factors) that are not two different refinements of a common partition, the original polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. For instance, $(1,2,4,5,6)$ and $(2,6,10)$ are not incompatible, but $(3,3)$ and $(2,4)$ are.